# Is there a way to save a tab-set in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, history, browser-tabs

I know how and have set Firefox to remember and reopen the tabs that were last set, but sometimes I have another window open and if it gets closed last, then I lose my first tab-set.

Is there some way to save a complete 'state', and be able to call it up when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Bookmarks toolbar you can put a folder there containing the links to your required sites (Right click toolbar then "New Folder" and drag required bookmarks in). Click on the folder, then "Open All in Tabs" allows you to get the required result (even with other tabs open if you don't want to close them).

Comment: You can also "Bookmarks > Bookmark All Tabs...". You then get prompted to create a folder in which to place all your tabs/bookmarks. And, as BrianA suggests, you can later "Open All in Tabs". However, I have encountered [a bug with "Bookmark All Tabs..."](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446171) in that the page title is not always saved!? Also, creating a bookmark  obviously does not save the tab history, as saving the session does.

Comment: After 4.0 you have to right-click on a tab and choose Bookmark All Tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You'd try a firefox add-on : [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2324/)

Answer (score 1):

Protecting opened tabs is just one little feature of this add-on : [Tab Kit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5447/)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the extensions mentioned above, but I use [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/).  In addition to the requested session manager, there are also options for the way that tabs are opened, closed, where they're opened, etc.  AFAIK, multi-window support for the session manager is included, however I turn on single window mode.